# Four different functions with different return type, same error

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

I am studying scala and slick. And I got an error like this:

```
found :   Option[Int]
required: Int
  def update(c: Color): Int = findById(c.id).update(c)
```

I am not sure what is `found` and `required` stand for. So I add other functions:

```
def update(c: Color): Int          = findById(c.id).update(c)
def update2(c: Color): Option[Int] = findById(c.id).update(c)
def update3(c: Color): String      = findById(c.id).update(c)
def update4(c: Color): Unit        = findById(c.id).update(c)
```

And expecting different `found` and `required`, but same error came out:

```
found :   Option[Int]
required: Int
  def update(c: Color): Int = findById(c.id).update(c)

found :   Option[Int]
required: Int
  def update2(c: Color): Option[Int] = findById(c.id).update(c)

found :   Option[Int]
required: Int
  def update3(c: Color): String      = findById(c.id).update(c)

found :   Option[Int]
required: Int
  def update4(c: Color): Unit        = findById(c.id).update(c)
```

Why same error came out? What is found and required stand for?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the error message is this part of your code

```
findById(c.id)
```

This part is the same for all four examples given. Thus the same error message.

**findById( id )** expects an *Int* as an argument but **c.id** returns an *Option[Int]*.

A possible solution would be to map over **c.id**

```
c.id map ( id => findById(id) update c  )
```

then it would return an Option[Int] as required by your **update2**.

Or you could use a **for comprehension** which would return an **Int** as your function **update** requires.

```
for {
  id <- c.id
  elem = findBy(id)
} yield elem.update(c)
```